# Any thoughts on this Spring Boot start variant to build specifical bean at earliest possible time?

Tags: spring-boot

The challenge is to build a specifical bean at the earliest possible time. That bean is needed for the further initialization process. The classes that need this particular bean do not autowire it, but only access static fields directly.

In principle, it would be possible to demand a dependency with `@Dependson`, but I don't want to add this annotation to all relevant classes. Unfortunately, Spring Boot has no option to suggest a start order for beans.

I have now come up with the following working solution:

```java
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder()
        .parent(ApplicationProperties.class)
        .child(Application.class)
        .run(args);
```

This way `ApplicationProperties.class` gets it's own context as parent and seems to being initialized before the main application context with `Application.class` gets built up.

### My question now is:

Is there anything against starting the application this way and can I be sure that the parent context is always built before the child context?

Many thanks for any information

### Edit:

As requested, here the `ApplicationProperties.class`:

```java
public class ApplicationProperties {

    public static final String AUTH_LOGIN_SUCCESS_ADMIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/admin";
    //...

    public static boolean EMAIL_CONFIRMATION;
    //...

    public ApplicationProperties(@Autowired Environment env) {
        this.init(env);
    }

    private void init(Environment env) {
        EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = env.getProperty("application.security.registration.email-confirmation", Boolean.class, false);
        //...
    }
}
```

It is a simple class for static properties, no annotation added and therefore no duplicate initialization when `Application.class` does it's classpath scanning. The only reason this has to be intialized as bean is to get access to Spring Boot's Environment.

Comment: could you please share your ApplicationProperties.class ?

Comment: ok but what do you do in this class? You have omitted some information and is not clear what is the purpose of that class

Comment: just initialization of static field EMAIL_CONFIRMATION is the purpose of it?

Comment: Yes, this class only provides application properties in form of static properties combining programmatical properties which the application needs at severeal places and properties the administrator can set via config-file or JVM system parameters.

Comment: please check my answer bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot startup is done in steps and when each step starts there are [application events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.spring-application.application-events-and-listener) sent via publishing mechanism. This allows the developer to intervene **but with caution** as described in docs during those steps.

Just for the purpose of this question, OP wants just to initialize some static field of some class before the context and beans are loaded, after the environment is loaded. This can safely happen with one of the published events in the step `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent`

As described in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.spring-application.application-events-and-listeners)

> An ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent is sent when the Environment to
> be used in the context is known but before the context is created.

So you can create your listener

```
public class EnvPreparedListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent>
{
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event)
    {
     ApplicationProperties.EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = event.getEnvironment().getProperty("application.security.registration.email-confirmation", Boolean.class, false);
    }
}
```

And then register this listener in your `@SpringBootApplication` class with

```
  @SpringBootApplication
  public class ServiceLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ServiceLauncher.class).listeners(new EnvPreparedListener()).run();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Great answer, I like this solution very much without detours via inheriting contexts. Many thanks for this tip. Just out of curiosity: would my variant still be ok or in principle questionable?